# Copy data from one column to another of the same row based on condition using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with a worksheet named in-out. In the worksheet, there are 4 columns occupied with data where as two more columns are blanks.

col A : input/output name

col B : input name (blank)

col C : output name (blank)

col D : port-used name

col E : set_input/set_output

col F : value

The task that I need to do is to check on each line from 1 till last (around 90000 lines and going to be increased), if data in col E is equal to set_input, copy data in col A to cell in col B, and if data in col E is equal to set_output, copy data in col A to cell in col B.

May I know how can I start the VBA script, should i start by finding the last row first so that the program will loop till the last used row? Is it possible to check on each line and copy the data based on the condition?

I started writing the script below and I got stuck.

```
Sub Test()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim x As Integer

With Worksheets("in-out")
  LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Select
  For x = Range("E2") To LastRow
  If x = "set_input_" Then

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, it will loop through all cells with values in Column E:

- If value of cell in Column A is "set_input_" , it will copy the value from Column "A" to Column "B".
- If value of cell in Column A is "set_output_" , it will copy the value from Column "A" to Column "C".

***Note***: there's no need (and it's better to avoid) to use `Select`, you don't need to `.Range("E2:E" & LastRow).` (select the entire range, instead use fully qualified objects.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim x As Long

With Worksheets("in-out")
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To LastRow
        If .Range("E" & x).Value = "set_input_" Then
            .Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("A" & x).Value
        ElseIf .Range("E" & x).Value = "set_output_" Then
            .Range("C" & x).Value = .Range("A" & x).Value
        End If
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Shai Rado, thanks for the note and the code works. thanks !!